# Load images from gallery onto MapsActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, android-gallery

The plan is to have an app displaying the pictures of your gallery onto a map in the exact spot where the picture was taken.
We have code to load the images into an array and read the location of each image (through the Exif data).

How can you load the images onto the map without them being saved into the drawable xml file but straight out of the array they are loaded into?

Comment: Should not that depend on the type of map you use?

Comment: We are using the MapsActivity from AndroidStudio so it's basically google maps.

Comment: One clarification: do you want the markers to show as images or do you want to first click on a marker and it displays the image?

Comment: the picture should show up by default and you can view it in full screen when you click on it.